# Qt/c++ equivalent to php routine

Tags: php, c++, qt, porting

I have the following code in Qt

```
    QString message = "somemessage";
    QString key = "somekey";
    QString hashed = QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(message,
                                                   key,
                                                 QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toBase64();
```

It outputs

```
8b0CA+VJBGMPVqKkygWeKuSVuquLc1vi/k9fPR8ZhXg=
```

In php I would do something like this:

```
    $msg = "somemessage";
    $key = "somekey";
    base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$msg,$key,true));
```

Which outputs the correct result I'm looking for:

```
olsHfSnlLo5cpuBqSzfzERE3Hma0kFSo9YgCacOqCCw=
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt documentation for [QMessageAuthenticationCode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmessageauthenticationcode.html) says the parameters should be in QByteArray. How did you even manage to get this code compiled? I wrote a small program with your code (for Qt) and managed to get the same result for the php code too. [php code result](https://ideone.com/EchCfl)

This piece of code gives me the same result as the above php code result.

```
QByteArray ke = "somekey";
QByteArray msg = "somemessage";
QString hashed = QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(msg,
                                        ke,
                                        QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toBase64();
qDebug() << hashed;
```